# How to account for move order in chess board evaluation

Tags: artificial-intelligence, evaluation, chess, alpha-beta-pruning

I am programming a Chess AI using an alpha-beta pruning algorithm that works at fixed depth. I was quite surprised to see that by setting the AI to a higher depth, it played even worse. But I think I figured it why so.

It currently works that way : All positions are listed, and for each of them, every other positions from that move is listed and so on... Until the fixed depth is reached : the board is evaluated by checking what pieces are present and by setting a value for every piece types. Then, the value bubbles up to the root using the minimax algorithm with alpha-beta.
But I need to account for the move order. For instance, there is two options, a checkmate in 2 moves, and another in 7 moves, then the first one has to be chosen. The same thing goes to taking a queen in whether 3 or 6 moves.
But since I only evaluate the board at the deepest nodes and that I only check the board as the evaluation result, it doesn't know what was the previous moves were.

I'm sure there is a better way to evaluate the game that can account for the way the pieces moved through the search.

EDIT: I figured out why it was playing weird. When I searched for moves (depth 5), it ended with a AI move (a MAX node level). By doing so, it counted moves such as taking a knight with a rook, even if it made the latter vulnerable (the algorithm cannot see it because it doesn't search deeper than that).
So I changed that and I set depth to 6, so it ends with a MIN node level.
Its moves now make more sense as it actually takes revenge when attacked (what it sometimes didn't do and instead played a dumb move).

However, it is now more defensive than ever and does not play : it moves its knight, then moves it back to the place it was before, and therefore, it ends up losing.
My evaluation is very standard, only the presence of pieces matters to the node value so it is free to pick the strategy it wants without forcing it to do stuff it doesn't need to.
Consedering that, is that a normal behaviour for my algorithm ? Is it a sign that my alpha-beta algorithm is badly implemented or is it perfectly normal with such an evaluation function ?

Comment: Alpha-beta needs information about previously evaluated lines. Not the moves themselves, but the _alpha_ and _beta_ values. In English, these mean roughly: "I can already force a score of _alpha_ using a previous line so, if my opponent has any defense leading to a score lower than _alpha_, I can stop evaluating all the remaining moves in this position." Therefore, once you discover a mate in 2, you propagate that score for the remainder of the analysis and use it to prune the mate in 7.

Comment: @C.Frâncu Okay I agree that it's what the algorithm should do. But if I only evaluate my board at the highest depth (and therefore check for mate at this very depth), it cannot discover a mate in 2, because it only sees the result of, for instance, 8 moves (if the depth is set to 8). And this is a problem for the algorithm is just delaying the mate (since after every move it can go deeper in the search).

Comment: That depends on your implementation. Ideally, at depth 2 you should realize that, since there are no legal moves, the game must end somehow (either mate or stalemate). What does your algorithm do when the move generation returns no moves?

Comment: So I need to search for mate at every node ? I see what I've been doing wrong... Indeed, the algorithm does nothing if no legal moves are returned, so unless the mate is at the highest score, it will just ignore every moves that ends up with checkmate. So I'll fix that. But will it change its weird playing when I increase depth ? Because it feels like it is changing strategy at each move.

Comment: The "strategy" exhibited by the software would be expected to change when the depth changes, but almost always in a positive correlation (higher depth --> better play). If it is consistently playing worse at higher depth, then you almost certainly have a bug in the code, which is very easy to do. Alpha-beta is somewhat tricky to code.

Comment: @JeffY That is my assumption too. I fixed the mate issue, it works much better now. But it doesn't change a thing for when it doesn't come to a checkmate. Instead of mate, let's imagine it can take a queen in whether 6 or 2 moves, the two moves will seem equivalent to it (as it doesn't depend on the chosen path but on the board's result). I have a particular situation that bothers me (it sacrifices a knight and doesn't take its bishop back). I'll edit my main post and expose it to you.

Comment: I have edited my main post. According to some research I did, I must be experiencing about the Horizon Effect.

Comment: As to strange play, consider that if you are counting material *only* in your evaluation function, then the vast majority of opening lines (anything without any captures) will *all* evaluate exactly equal, so the AI will just select "randomly" between them (actually depending on the algorithm's move-generation ordering).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to select the shortest path to a win, you probably also want to select the longest path to a loss.  If you were to try to account for this in the evaluation function, you would have to the path length along with the score and have separate evaluation functions for min and max.  It's a lot of complex and confusing overhead.

The standard way to solve this problem is with an iterative deepening approach to the evaluation.  First you search deep enough for 1 move for all players, then you run the entire search again searching 2 moves for each player, etc until you run out of time.  If you find a win in 2 moves, you stop searching and you'll never run into the 7 moves situation.  This also solves your problem of searching odd depths and getting strange evaluations.  It has many other benefits, like always having a move ready to go when you run out of time, and some significant algorithmic improvements because you won't need the overhead of tracking visited states.

As for the defensive play, that is a little bit of the horizon effect and a little bit of the evaluation function.  If you have a perfect evaluation function, the algorithm only needs to see one move deep.  If it's not perfect (and it's not), then you'll need to get much deeper into search.  Last I checked, algorithms that can run on your laptop and see about 8 plys deep (a ply is 1 move for each player) can compete with strong humans.

Answer (score 1):

In order to let the program choose the shortest checkmate, the standard approach is to give a higher value to mates that occur closer to the root. Of course, you must detect checkmates, and give them some score.

Also, from what you describe, you need a quiescence search.

All of this (and much more) is explained in the chess programming wiki. You should check it out:

- https://www.chessprogramming.org/Checkmate#MateScore
- https://www.chessprogramming.org/Quiescence_Search